# How to call a js function explicitly from phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, configuration, phtml, requirejs

I have the following file

> Vendor/Catalog/view/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Content of that file as follows

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var $block \Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable*/
$_product    = $block->getProduct();
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php //var_dump($block->getJsonConfig())?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <div class="field configurable required">
            <label class="label" for="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>">
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-selector="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select">
                    <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <script id="configurable_attribute_script" type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar('gallery_switch_strategy',
                        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct') ?: 'replace'; ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    </script> 
<?php endif;?>
```

I'm trying to call a function of following js file

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

I added following code in above phtml file

```
<script>
 define('configurable_attribute_change',['jquery','configurableJs'],function($,configurable){
 configurable._initializeOptions();
 });
 require(['configurable_attribute_change']);
</script>
```

I'm just trying to call a function to see if its possible to make a call.
I even added a following require.js file

> app/code/Vendor/Catalog/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

with following content

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurableJs: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

But I'm getting this error in console.
[image]

Is there a way to call configurable.js functions?